# How to deal with floor effect

Tags: references, psychometrics, validation

I am in the process of validating a five-items scale for measuring dependence on substance 'X'. I have collected data from 98 people who used the substance under consideration at least once weekly for three years. The items showed a good internal consistency (Cronbach's alpha = 0.81). I also did factor analysis. The factor analysis yielded that all items have communalities of .46 and above and extracted a single factor that accounts for about 57% of the variance. Factor loadings ranged from .68 to .81. However, all items have severe floor effect: 41% to 66%. How should I deal with this floor effect? May I just overlook this effect since other measures of the psychometric properties of the scale are acceptable? I would also appreciate if you could indicate references that I can consult.

Comment: Are you trying to identify (1) people who will or do use the substance or (2) the level of use of people who are users?  You say you have data on users only.  So it would seem you can only address #2 above.  Also, have you calculated a correlation between the scale score and the level of usage and looked at a scatter plot of the relationship between scale score and level of usage?  If so, what did you find?

Comment: As an aside, since the criterion you are using is a self-report of usage (which seems easy to get) there must be a reason for trying to predict usage with a scale. I am curious about that reason.